# Can this be Mobius inverted?

Tags: mobius-inversion

Let $n\in N$.

Let $\mu (n)$ be the classical Mobius function. In other words, it vanishes at square-full numbers, equals $+1$ if $n$ has an even number of distinct prime factors, and equals $-1$ is $n$ has an odd number of distinct prime factors.

Let $p_i$ be the $i$-th prime.

Let $p_{max} (n)$ be the largest prime factor of $n$.

Let $p_{nextmax} (n)$ be the first prime larger than $p_{max} (n)$.

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be integer functions of real variables. In other words, $f,g:R \to Z$.

Of interest is the following identity:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n p_{nextmax} (n) \leq x} \mu (n) g\left( \frac{x}{n} \right) $$

We notice that this sum runs over $n$, and roughly $n \leq \sqrt{x}$, not $n\leq x$, because of the condition $n p_{nextmax} (n) \leq x$. Thus, an easier variant of this question considers the identity:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\leq \sqrt{x}} \mu (n) g\left( \frac{x}{n} \right) $$

Or, even more generally, the identity:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\leq y\leq x} \mu (n) g\left( \frac{x}{n} \right) $$

Can the above identities be Mobius inverted? If so, what would the result be?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the inspiration behind this problem? (not that there has to be one)

Comment: @Dis-integrating Hi. Yes, there is the inspiration behind this. It's RH. I expect this identity to be Mobius invertable. One should use the general Mobius inversion that is defined in abstract form over rings. I'm not quite fluent at abstract Mobius theory, so I decided to ask the question directly. The answer would save lots of time. Besides, I expect the answer to be rather trivial, because one simply has to prove that all conditions are met to use an abstract form of Mobius theory. I like your nick-name, Dis-integrating!

Comment: what does the $m$ stand for in $p_m(n)$?

Comment: @roger Hi. Subscript $m$ in $p_m (n)$ stands for "maximal".

Comment: ok then it should be $n= \prod_{i=1}^{p_m(n)} p_i^{e_i(n)}$ then no?

Comment: also in the identity with $f$ and $g$ does $x/n$ have to be an integer? I think it should be for it to be Mobius invertible.

Comment: @roger No, index $i$ counts primes $p_i$. So for $i=1$ one has $p_1 =2$ in the prime factorization. For $i=2$ one has $p_2 = 3$, for $i=3$ a prime factor $p_3 = 5$ enters the prime factorization product. Eventually, there's the maximal prime $p_m (n)$ such that $e_m (n) \ne 0$.

Comment: yes you're right sorry.

Comment: @roger Ratio $x/n$ need not be an integer in general. This is true for classical Mobius inversion as well. Functions $f$ and $g$ can have support in, say, [0,$+\infty$>.

Comment: The notation is poor. Both "m" and "m+1" are used as names, rather than values. I think it would be better to have $v(n) = \{\max m\big|p_m | m\}$ where $p_m$ is the $m$-th prime.  Then $p_{v(n)}$ is the largest prime that divides $n$ and $p_{v(n)+1}$ is the next prime.

Comment: Here's a pdf document link that explains the general Mobius inversion with examples: http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/actas-sjtn2007-BenitoNavasVarona.pdf .

Comment: @marty cohen Hi. True. But, index $m$ does label the $m$-th prime, so it's useful both ways: as a label as well as the actual number. Prime $p_m$ is the $m$-th prime indeed. It's also "maximal". I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I think this adds to the confusion. For example,what is the difference between $p_m$ and $p_m(n)$? What is $p_{2m}(n)$?

Comment: @marty cohen True. Luckily, $p_{2m} (n)$ isn't used here... Since $p_m \equiv p_m (n)$, i found this useful, so I used just $m$, because $n$ is the only variable here. I'll change this if it really amounts to confusion. Thanks.

Comment: @marty cohen Done!

Comment: is the "identity" $f(x) = \sum_{(...)} \mu(n) g(x/n)$ just a definition for $f(x)$? or do you have specific functions $f,g$ in mind?

Comment: @Harry Richman Hi. I have specific functions in mind. Unfortunately, I cannot disclose what these specific functions are. However, the result should not depend on functions $f$ and $g$, simply because if the result holds for any particular pair of functions $F$ and $G$ with some support, then it holds for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$ with the same support. See, for instance, http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/actas-sjtn2007-BenitoNavasVarona.pdf .